# c++ read socket timeout

Tags: c++, sockets, select

I've problems to read a socket.
I use Select to check if data is present and read to read the socket data.

```
FD_ZERO(&rfd);
FD_SET(socket, &rfd);
this->timeout.tv_sec = 0;//need both setted
this->timeout.tv_usec = MS_500 *  1000;
setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&timeout, sizeof timeout);
cout<<"try to read"<<endl;
if (select(socket + 1, &rfd, NULL, NULL, &timeout) > 0) {
  if ((readedByte = read(socket, &buffer, sizeof(buffer))) < 0) {
     cout<<"ERROR"<<endl;
     PLOG_ERROR_(MemoryHandler::INFO) << "Error reading serial";
   } else {
     buffer[readedByte - 1] = '\0';
     string tempString = buffer;
     cout<<tempString<<endl;
}
```

Sometime happens that socket return a value >0 and read gets stuck.
How I can set the timeout correctly for the read?

Comment: This should not be happening. `select` should return the number of descriptors where read would not block, and you only have one descriptor.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but I don't knwo why sometime happens.
The read blocking was caused by a setting into socket initializzation 
 fcntl(*socket, F_SETFL, 0);

But I don't understand why fails

Comment: Solved.

After a restart a process that Should be stopped was restarted, and the 2 processes were in conflict